# Index of the endomorphism ring of an abelian surface

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, abelian-varieties

For an abelian surface $A/\mathbb{Q}$ such that $R:=\mathrm{End}_{\mathbb{Q}}(A)$ is an order in a real quadratic field $K$ (so a $\mathrm{GL}_2$-type surface), is there a bound on the index $[O_K : R]$ of the ring inside the maximal order $O_K$?

Answer (score 2):

There is a conjecture of Coleman asserting that up to isomorphism, there are only finitely many possible rings $\operatorname{End}_{\mathbf{Q}}(A)$ where $A$ varies among the abelian surfaces defined over $\mathbf{Q}$ (see Bruin, Victor Flynn, Gonzalez, Rotger, *On finiteness conjectures for endomorphism algebras of abelian surfaces*). This would imply that the answer to your question is yes. On the other hand, this is a very difficult conjecture, so there might be an easier way to tackle your question.

Comment: Thanks Francois, I am aware of this conjecture of Coleman, which would of course imply the answer to my question. I guess what I'm asking is whether it is known if the quantity $[O_K : R]$ is bounded, even for a fixed $K$?

Comment: @SunRa The index of the Hecke algebra is linked with congruences between the two associated eigenforms, so maybe the theory of congruences helps here.

Comment: Do you know how they are linked exactly?

Comment: @SunRa As an example, take $A=A_f$ with $f$ a newform of weight 2 with coefficients in the order $R=\mathbf{Z}[m\sqrt{2}]$, then the Galois conjugate newform $f'$ is congruent to $f$ modulo $2m\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Yes that could be helpful. When $A_f$ is associated to $f$, Is it that End$_{\mathbb{Q}}(A_f) = \mathbb{Z}[ \{a_i(f)\}_i ]$ or the weaker statement that End$_{\mathbb{Q}}(A_f) \otimes \mathbb{Q} = \mathbb{Q}( \{a_i(f)\}_i )$. I hoped it was the former but I cannot find a precise reference for this. Also Prop 2.5.4 of J. Wilson's thesis implies that associated to $f$ there should also be a surface with real multiplication by the maximal order (because there is an isogeny).

Comment: @SunRa You're right, this is a subtle question. The endomorphism ring of $A_f$ certainly contains the order generated by the Fourier coefficients of $f$, at least if $A_f$ is defined as the optimal quotient $J_0(N)/I_f J_0(N)$ or $J_1(N)/I_f J_1(N)$, where $I_f$ denotes the annihilator of $f$ in the Hecke algebra. Regarding the reverse inclusion, the only result I know in this direction is Mazur's result that the endomorphism ring of $J_0(N)$ is generated by the Hecke operators and the Atkin-Lehner involution. This is a problem I would like to understand more.

Comment: Thanks, this does seem to be a subtle issue. I think I will need to understand this result of Mazur better. So it seems like at present all I can say is that if the index is $d= [ O_K : \mathbb{Z} [ \{a_i (f) \}_i] ]$, then $\mathbb{Z} [ \{a_i (f) \}_i ] \hookrightarrow End_{\mathbb{Q}}(B)$ and $[ O_K : End_{\mathbb{Q}}(B) ] \leq d$ where $B$ is any abelian surface isogenous to $A_f$.